# Showing recipient name in the "Sent Email" label/folder in Gmail

Tags: gmail

When I see my sent emails in my "Sent Email" folder in Gmail, if my email was not responded yet, I see the word "me" as sender.

[image]

But instead of the word "me", I would like to see the recipient name. I think it's obvious that "me" sent the email.

Is there any way to configure Gmail to show the recipient name of my sent emails in "Sent Email" folder?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. The regular Gmail interface doesn't support that kind of categorization.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new beta version of Gmail by clicking on the gear icon in the top right corner of the window. In the new version it says: `To: <name here>`. I hope this is what you were looking for.